# Prevent iPhone from connecting to WiFi when activating Personal WiFi Hotspot

Tags: iphone, wifi, tethering

Every time I turn on my mobile WiFi hotspot on my iPhone, it works great unless I am in range of a remembered WiFi hotspot that iPhone itself can connect to -- iPhone silently opts to use any WiFi data stream instead of my cellular stream, the latter of which I always prefer.

My phone's data connection is much faster than my WiFi connection, and it often takes me a while to realize why my iPhone's hotspot it so horribly slow: it is connected to the very WiFi access point I am attempting to circumvent!!

Is there a way to prevent iPhone from itself connecting to WiFi when broadcasting a WiFi hotspot of its own, without "forget"-ing all relevant hotspot encryption keys?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to connect to wifi while broadcasting a hotspot on iPhone (note: this is physically possible, but I'm not sure Apple allows it.) You may be using the Bluetooth feature of the personal hotspot while being connected to a wireless network...

Comment: I wish Apple would add a feature to disable a wifi connection without forgetting it (deleting the password).

Comment: I have a similar issue at home if our router can't connect to the wider internet but is still visible locally and causing devices to connect to it